# SFDX commands not working from API version 52.0 in CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, api-version

Today, when I tried to use the regular command to fetch list of orgs of Salesforce in CLI terminal, it throws me an error/warning as below:

[image: Warning Message]

And I'm unable to login to my salesforce orgs too. Like no SFDX commands are working in short. As a temporary fix, i have changed the version to 51.0 by using below command:

`sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=51.0`

But, I'm looking for a permanent fix? Please let me know if anyone has overcome this issue fix.

Comment: it's just a warning that displays every time, it doesn't prevent it from running. Do you have any connected orgs? What version are you running `sfdx -v`?

Comment: Why the hell will they remove connectedStatus ? :/

Comment: @sfdx -v Yes, I have 4 orgs connected in my CLI. But after the update, I'm unable open any unless if i set the Version to 51.0 manually.